# python precedence in Comparisons for boolean expressions

Tags: python

why python 3 evaluate `3 in [] == False` to be `False`?
But I know `(3 in []) == False` is `True`.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority,
> which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise
> operation. Also unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the
> interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:
>
> ```
> comparison    ::=  or_expr (comp_operator or_expr)*
> comp_operator ::= "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="
>                   | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
> ```
>
> Comparisons yield boolean values: True or False.
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
> to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
> cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Consider the case `1 < 2 < 3`. This really breaks out to `(1 < 2) and (2 < 3)`

So the statement `3 in [] == False` breaks out to `(3 in []) and ([] == False)`